# how to scroll text field horizontal in android?

Tags: android, android-layout

My UI is

UserName  : Textfield

Password  :  Textfield

```
Button
```

I am making simple UI in android .Actually I am facing few problem

1) Edit field is not scrolling horizontally if the text come more it comes down .

2) password is shown .

3) If I want to show this in pop up screen mean a small window how it is possible ?

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/username"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="31dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="108dp"
    android:textSize="12sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:text="UserName" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/usename_edit"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/username"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/username"
    android:layout_marginLeft="35dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/username"
    android:ems="10" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/username_password"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/username"
    android:layout_below="@+id/usename_edit"
    android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
     android:textStyle="bold|italic"
    android:text="Password" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/edit_password"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/username_password"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/username_password"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/usename_edit"
    android:ems="10" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/edit_password"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="62dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:text="ClickMe" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer 1:

add this line in your java code where the text view is defined

```
textview.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
```

and add this in your xml file

```
 android:fadeScrollbars="false"
 android:scrollbars="horizontal"
```

Answer 2:

For your password EditText add this line in your xml file

```
 android:inputType="textPassword"
```

Answer 3:

Use Dialog for the same. Something like this

```
myDialog = new Dialog(Login.this);
            myDialog.setContentView(R.layout.emailpop);
            myDialog.setTitle("Login");
            myDialog.setCancelable(true);

            et_f = (EditText) myDialog.findViewById(R.id.et_pass);
            et_f.setText(et1.getText().toString());
            t5 = (TextView) myDialog.findViewById(R.id.textView4);
            t5.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            // for OK
            Button ok = (Button) myDialog.findViewById(R.id.button1);
            ok.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {


            });
            myDialog.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

try this by code..

```
usename_edit.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(true);
```

and

```
edit_password.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(true);
```

there is also can done from xml by setting scrollbars prop. of edittext

```
 scrollbars="horizonatal"
```

for password problem set this prop. to editext in xml:

```
android:inputType="textPassword"
```

Comment: In password text is display

Comment: how to remove keyboard when user click any where in window

Answer (score 0):

> 1) Edit field is not scrolling horizontally if the text come more it
>   comes down .

Add an attribute to your `EditText` as `android:singleLine="true"`

> 2) password is shown .

Add an attribute to your as `android:inputType="textPassword"` to the `edit_password`

> 3) If I want to show this in pop up screen mean a small window how it is
>   possible

You'll need an `AlertDialog` for this.
Checkout [this](http://www.androidhive.info/2011/09/how-to-show-alert-dialog-in-android/) tutorial.

Comment: how to remove keyboard  when user click any where in window

Answer (score 0):

**1)** to make it `scrollable` use: `.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(true);` in your activity class, or this  `scrollbars="horizonatal"` in your `edittext xml`.

**2)** to make the password ***********: use         `android:inputType="textPassword"`
 in your    `edittext xml`.

**3)** to show a popup, you can use [`alertDialog`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.html).